# Como mapear un array priorizando el valor de una propiedad

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

Lo que deseo es que dentro de mi array quiero mapear las imagenes (en este caso **imageTerms**), eso lo puedo hacer normal, pero o que busco es que quiero que se muestre de menor a mayor, dependiendo de la prioridad que tengo en el objeto **priority**.

Este es mi array

```js
0:
description: "Interbank"
descriptionTerms: "Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet."
image: "49e5d62a-d884-47b3-8855-e658170aaef9___8e988904f62f8b6d32e7c0d6b6a553fe.png"
imageTerms: "7e4b6bf7-966d-4735-9471-9b5603b72186___8e988904f62f8b6d32e7c0d6b6a553fe.png"
linkTerms: "https://www.realplaza.com/terminos-y-condiciones/descuento-interbank"
priority: {value: "2", label: "2"}
titleTerms: "¡Promo crédito Interbank!"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
description: "BBVA"
descriptionTerms: "Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet."
image: "0cae5c1a-2044-4ccb-b770-bd735a0948e9___43cba8cb0900ace28b862e935822e828.png"
imageTerms: "690c2e16-97aa-4a8b-8b47-5d818307ba95___b1c731760d3e57839a89667b04edf308.png"
linkTerms: "https://www.realplaza.com/terminos-y-condiciones/descuento-interbank"
priority: {value: "1", label: "1"}
titleTerms: "¡Promo crédito BBVA!"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Al mapear las imagenes, me pinta primero el de interbank (prioridad 2) y el segundo el de BBVA (prioridad 1), lo que deseo saber es como puedo mapearlo dependiendo de la prioridad de menor a mayor que se vea primero el de BBVA ya que tiene prioridad 1 y el segundo Interbank ya que tiene prioridad 2 y si es que tiene otra prioridad mayor pues se ordene de menor a mayor dependiendo de la prioridad , por ahora solo tengo este codigo.

```js
          {badgesImagesUrl.map((badgeImage: any, index: number) => (
            <div className={tooltipContainer()} key={`${index}-icon`} onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation(),
                e.preventDefault(),
                setModalTerms(badgeImage),
                setOpen(true)
            }}>

              <Image
                src={`https://realplaza.vtexassets.com/assets/vtex.file-manager-graphql/images/${badgeImage?.image}`}
              />
              <span className={tooltip()}>{badgeImage?.description}</span>
            </div>
          ))}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar , muchas gracias !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, te voy a presentar dos:

### Ordenar primero el Array

Puedes ordenar el array utilizando sort, ejemplo:

```js
const array = [
  {name: "FirstBank", priority: {value: 1, label: 1}},
  {name: "SecondBack", priority: {value: 0, label: 0}},
]

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.priority.value - b.priority.value
}))
```

Luego hacer el render con el `map` normalmente como lo haces.
El `sort` es recomendable que lo hagas siempre que cambie tu Array, es decir, no lo utilices en el render, si no utilízalo por ejemplo en `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    propBadges.sort(((a, b) => {
        return a.priority.value - b.priority.value
    })

    setStateBadges(propBadges)
}, [propBadges])
```

Lo negativo de este metodo es que deber recorrer todo tu array cada vez que cambia para ordernarlo.

### Utilizar `order` con css

La siguiente forma es mas fácil y para mi es mucho mejor.
En css hay una propiedad llamada `order` que ordena (valga la redundancia) los elementos del html, podrias utilizarla de esta manera:

```
    {badgesImagesUrl.map((badgeImage: any, index: number) => (
        <div style={{order: badgeImage.priority.value}} className={tooltipContainer()} key={`${index}-icon`} onClick= 
            {(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation(),
                e.preventDefault(),
                setModalTerms(badgeImage),
                setOpen(true)
            }}>

            <Image
                src={`https://realplaza.vtexassets.com/assets/vtex.file-manager-graphql/images/${badgeImage?.image}`}
            />
            <span className={tooltip()}>{badgeImage?.description}</span>
        </div>
    ))}
```

Puedes leer mas aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Hay diferentes formas pero estas son las que se me ocurrieron, tu prueba y elige la que creas conveniente.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Me ayudaste bastante , no sabia esa del css , gracias ! :)